# Redirect very long links to shorter ones

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect very long links like this one:

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?module=news&type=user&func=display&iframe=true&width=80%&height=80%&articletitle=title-of-article&sid=2088&comments_startnum=101
```

to clearer and shorter links like this one:

```
http://www.mysite.com/title-of-article/
```

So I tried with this htaccess rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^module=news\&type=user\&func=display\&iframe=true\&width=([0-9]+)%\&height=([0-9]+)%\&articletitle=([a-z0-9]+)\&title=([a-z0-9]+)&sid=([0-9]+)\&comments_startnum=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /$3/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this really long URL already linked in your code? or are you trying to make pretty URL's?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's an old URL that I want to redirect to a more engine friendly URL.